# Stack Overflow error when attempting to create array

Tags: java, arrays, stack-overflow

I'm trying to create an array of 10 total Account objects, but when I try to run it I get a Stack Overflow error.  I have no idea why I'm getting the error and Google hasn't come up with anything.  Thanks for any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Account {

private int id;
private double balance;
private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private Account[] atm = new Account[10];

public Account(){
    id = 0;
    balance = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < atm.length; i++){
        atm[i] = new Account(); //Here is where Eclipse says the problem is
        atm[i].setID(i);
        atm[i].setBalance(100.0);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see what happens: when you create an Account object it creates a bunch of new Accounts, each of which create a bunch more Accounts, each of which create a bunch more Accounts, each of which create a bunch more Accounts, each of which create a bunch more Accounts, each of which create a bunch more...

Do you see a pattern here? It's called recursion ad infinitum, or at least until stack memory runs out -- which causes a StackOverflowException.

Now for a solution:
I would not have my Account class hold an Account array, but rather would put that array in another class, say AccountCollection or Accounts or perhaps even Customer if all the Accounts are to be held by one customer.